# 'Error on the order of 0.5cm'?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, error-analysis, experimental-technique

This is a quick question about reporting approximate errors in a physics lab report. There was an error which I did not account for exactly in my experiment, but I want to acknowledge it as a source of systematic error (specifically, I did not account for lens thickness in an optics experiment). I do not know the exact error, but an guessing it would be about 3-4mm or so? Saying that it was 'on the order of 1mm' seems a gross underestimation, whereas 'order of 1cm' is both an overestimate and would severely impact the validity(?) of my results (not sure if I am using the right experimental terminology here).

Should I just say that the error from this would have been a few millimeters? I think this is ok in a paper too?

Apologies for the elementary question- this is my first attempt at lab report writing.

Comment: If your best estimate is 3-4 mm, then you should simply quote that. Ideally add how you came to that estimate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facts are better than vague statements like "of the order of".

If you can show theoretically that a lens thickness of $d$ would change the interpretation of your results by $e$, then include that theory, and add something like

"The results shown did not take account of the finite thickness of the lens. The thickness was not measured, but is estimated to have been about 3-4mm. Ignoring this therefore creates systematic errors of about $x$ mm" where $x$ is whatever the theory predicts.

In "real life" experimental work, discovering with hindsight that you overlooked something important is entirely normal. A "science lab" situation is different (and unrealistic), because once the lab session is over you don't have any chance to repeat the procedure, or collect the missing data.

Comment: "Ignoring this therefore creates systematic errors of about xx mm" Is that really much different?  I understand your point, since the error is known he can explain it in his setup and show how to approximate the error.  The error being "on the order of" is less vague to me than "about" since at least "on the order of" gives upper and lower bounds.  I just don't agree with the implication of your first sentence.  The vagueness has nothing to do with the term "of the order of", but entirely to do with how the error is framed.